# Extract data out of object MongoDB and PHP (fuelphp)

Tags: php, mongodb, fuelphp

I am using MongoDB and FuelPHP. I successfully connected to MongoDB and can extract data. I already spent three days trying to figure out how to inject data into view.
My view is such:

```
<body>
<div class="middle">
    <p><?php if (isset($_id)){echo $_id;} ?></p>
    <p><?php if (isset($first_name)){echo $first_name;} ?></p>
    <p><?php if (isset($last_name)){echo $last_name;} ?></p>
</div>
</body>
```

My controller is:

```
class Controller_Home extends Controller {

public function action_index()
{
    $data['css'] = Asset::css(array('reset.css','main.css'));
    $results = Model_Home::get_results();

            //I thought all I have to do is this foreach loop and it would work
    foreach($results as $row => $val){
        $data = $val;
    }

    $this->response->body = View::factory('home/index', $data);
}
}
```

My var_dump() is:

```
        object(stdClass)#10 (2) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["_id"]=>
        object(MongoId)#13 (1) {
          ["$id"]=>
          string(24) "4ef82a27b238f02ed9000000"
        }
        ["cms"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(8) "Druapl_1"
        }
        ["first_name"]=>
        string(6) "Name_1"
        ["last_name"]=>
        string(10) "Lst_Name_1"
        ["skills"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          string(6) "html_1"
          [1]=>
          string(5) "css_1"
          [2]=>
          string(8) "jQuery_1"
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(5) {
        ["_id"]=>
        object(MongoId)#14 (1) {
          ["$id"]=>
          string(24) "4ef81a0dcf163c7da3e5c964"
        }
        ["cms"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(8) "Druapl_2"
        }
        ["first_name"]=>
        string(6) "Name_2"
        ["last_name"]=>
        string(10) "Lst_Name_2"
        ["skills"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          string(6) "html_2"
          [1]=>
          string(5) "css_2"
          [2]=>
          string(8) "jQuery_2"
        }
      }
    }
```

Now, it does work, but I only see the first item in my view for some reason:

```
4ef81a0dcf163c7da3e5c964

Name_2

Lst_Name_2

html_2

css_2

jQuery_2

Druapl_2
```

I think something goes terribly wrong in my old nemesis foreach loop...
Please help, this will certainly will help me improve my understanding of objects, foreach loops and frameworks in general. Thank you.

Comment: We need more information. Please show us a full document in the collection via db.collection.findOne() as well as the complete code via github so we can try to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with FuelPHP but it appears as though your $data variable is not formatted correctly. You have:

```
foreach($results as $row => $val){
    $data = $val;
}
```

Most likely you need it to be (You were overwriting the values each time you grabbed a new row):

```
foreach($results as $row => $val){
    $data['results'][$row] = $val;
}
```

Then on your view you should have something like (You weren't iterating through your results):

```
<body>
<div class="middle">
<?php foreach($results as $result): ?>
    <p><?php if (isset($result['_id'])){echo $result['_id'];} ?></p>
    <p><?php if (isset($result['first_name'])){echo $result['first_name'];} ?></p>
    <p><?php if (isset($result['last_name'])){echo $result['last_name'];} ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
</body>
```

However this is overly complicated in that you're iterating through the data twice.  You're better approach would probably be the following:

```
//Replace this:
foreach($results as $row => $val){
    $data['results'][$row] = $val;
}

//with this:
$data['results'] = $results;
```

Then in your view do the following:

```
<body>
<div class="middle">
<?php foreach($results as $result): ?>
    <p><?php if (isset($result['_id'])){echo $result['_id'];} ?></p>
    <p><?php if (isset($result['first_name'])){echo $result['first_name'];} ?></p>
    <p><?php if (isset($result['last_name'])){echo $result['last_name'];} ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
</body>
```

EDIT:

**Additional Information** on which this answer is based: (Assuming FuelPHP is like CodeIgniter which it appears to be)

```
$data['some_item'] = some_val;
$data['some_item2'] = some_val2;
```

when passed to the view becomes:

$some_item (which equates to some_val) and $some_item2 (which equates to some_val2)

Comment: Yes, thank you that worked in controller:  foreach($results as $row => $val){
    $data['results'][$row] = $val;
} :and this in the view: <?php foreach($results as $result): ?>
    <p><?php if (isset($result['_id'])){echo $result['_id'];} ?></p>
    <p><?php if (isset($result['first_name'])){echo $result['first_name'];} ?></p>
    <p><?php if (isset($result['last_name'])){echo $result['last_name'];} ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
Thank you!

Comment: and your second option worked too in the controller: $data['results'] = $results;
and in the view: <?php foreach($results as $result): ?>
    <p><?php if (isset($result['_id'])){echo $result['_id'];} ?></p>
    <p><?php if (isset($result['first_name'])){echo $result['first_name'];} ?></p>
    <p><?php if (isset($result['last_name'])){echo $result['last_name'];} ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
foreach($results as $row => $val)
{
    $data[$row] = $val;
}
```

It is also possible to pass complete objects to the template instead of converting it to an array first.

Comment: Hi, your method, does not give me an error so it is a good thing. But my view is now empty. Do I need to restructure my view somehow. Also you've mentioned that " It is also possible to pass complete objects to the template" how would I do that? I feel that it is my only hope. I've tried so many things by now... Please let me know. Meanwhile I will keep looking.

Comment: You know julesj, it does work. When I do print_r($data["0"]) and print_r($data["0"]) I see my data but it gets lost somewhere in the controller to view  transfer. Or so it seems...

Comment: I think you are on to something julesj. But do you know how can I pass this data into view? I kinda can do it, but my approach is not friendly, not dynamic...

Comment: The key in `$data` is the name of the variable in your view. So, if you pass `$data['id']`, you can use `echo $id` in your view.

Comment: Your Mongo result object has multiple levels, so the `foreach` loop will not 'array-fy' the complete object successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know php but it seems to me that you are iterating over all the key, value pairs in the result objects:

```
foreach($results as $row => $val)
{
    $data = $val;
}
```

Why not just say

```
foreach($results as $obj)
{
    $data = $obj
}
```

Then get the things you want out of the data object in the view:

```
<?php if (isset($data['_id'])){echo $data['_id'];} ?>
```

Again, I have no idea if thats how you do it in php but the idea is that you want to loop over results and then access attributes of each object, not iterate over the attributes.

Updated: fixed some of the code, I'm assuming fuel somehow passes local variables like data to the view but maybe it doesn't.

-Tyler

Comment: Thanks Tyler, just tried it, does not seem to work. Got this error "ErrorException [ Parsing Error ]: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ')'" then I tried this: echo $data['_id']; And I get ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: data. Anyway thanks for trying. I'll keep looking. I understand what you are telling me, but PHP is not my strength either.

Comment: Ah sorry, good luck. May I suggest reading the documentation for the MongoDB PHP driver here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php

Comment: Great, thanks. I am not sure how I overlooked this one. However, after going through it, I can select DB and collection, but I ran into to the same problem as before where only one record shows up. Either there is a bug somewhere or I simply not doing something right...